# preg_replace regex work on test but not on my server

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm creating an email template and try to solve an unknown problem that add a random number of 
 at the beginning of my tables.

So my preg_replace is: 
`preg_replace('/<br>(.*?)<table/s', "<br><table", $message)`

I tried it on these websites and it worked: 
preg_replace.onlinephpfunctions.com/
fr.functions-online.com/preg_replace.html

But on my server, it doesn't work, I also tried a preg_match_all but it doesn't work too.

Here's the source code where I use it:
https://codeshare.io/GbrArM

Comment: Don't parse HTML with regex. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @bub It means that the preg_replace doesn't replace anything and a print_r of the preg_match_all return 0

Comment: since the regexp is the same on both sides, the problems lies within the content

Comment: @delboy1978uk Ok but what can I do to remove these <br> ?

Comment: @Calimero I copy/paste the content of my HTML page on these website to test it and it worked...

Comment: @Korvent then it's the environment

Comment: @Calimero On this website: http://preg_replace.onlinephpfunctions.com/ I can choose the PHP Version which is the same as mine

Comment: Check `phpinfo()` and ensure the PCRE extension is enabled

Comment: @apokryfos Yes it is...